# Divisão de números inteiros

Tags: php

olá, eu quero fazer um calculo do tipo:

Eu quero distribuir por exemplo 6 números inteiros em outros 5 números que começam em 0
ficando mais ou menos assim:
2 1 1 1 1

ou por exemplo 3 números inteiros em 5 números que começam a contar de zero:

1 1 1 0 0

Meu progresso foi algo do tipo:

```
<?php
$t = 5;
$i = 0;
$b = 0;
$numeros = array (
0,0,0,0
);
for($i; $i <= count($numeros)-1; $i++):

    for($b = $numeros[$i]; $b <= count($numeros)-1; $numeros[$i]++):

        $t--;
    endfor;
endfor;
echo "<br />";
echo $numeros[0];
?>
```

Comment: Coloque o código que já fez para ficar mais explícita a pergunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi bem a sua pergunta, acho que é isso que está procurando:

```
<?php

function distribui_inteiros($numero, $caixas) {
    echo "Distribuindo o número:  $numero em $caixas caixas.";
    $div = floor($numero / $caixas);
    $sobra = $numero - ($caixas * $div);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $caixas; $i++) {
        $caixa[$i] = $div;
        if($sobra > 0){
            $caixa[$i]++;
        }
        $sobra--;
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($caixa);
    echo '</pre>';
    return $caixa;
}

$resultado1 = distribui_inteiros(6, 5);
$resultado2 = distribui_inteiros(3, 5);
$resultado3 = distribui_inteiros(23, 6);
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

```
Distribuindo o número: 6 em 5 caixas.
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
)
Distribuindo o número: 3 em 5 caixas.
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
)
Distribuindo o número: 23 em 6 caixas.
Array
(
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 3
)
```

Se esta resposta lhe ajudou, fico grato se escolher a minha resposta e/ou marcá-la como útil (+1). Obrigado!

Comment: po, era isso mesmo valeu mlk :)

Comment: Tem um erro ainda... espera um pouco que atualizo para a versão correta!

Comment: Script corrigido e atualizado! Boa sorte!

Comment: obrigado, to aprendendo tudo aqui o que você fez rsrsrs